# Magento 2 override block not work properly

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I am overriding the **Catalog Search result block** but it is only showing **title** not **product listing**. Can anyone tell what i missed here?

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Test\Test\Block\Result" />
</config>
```

**Result.php**

```
namespace Test\Test\Block;




class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{

    public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __("Search results for: '%1'", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }



}
```

Comment: You have to put `di.xml` in `etc/frontend/di.xml` if it is in the frontend. I found this here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Unable-to-override-ListProduct-block-in-magento-2-2-5/m-p/103038/highlight/true#M5483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end i end up doing with **plugin**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="tesultchange" type="Test\Test\Model\Resultchange" sortOrder="10" /></type>
</config>
```

**Resultchange.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Model;

class Resultchange {


    public function aftergetSearchQueryText()
    {
        $test='abc';
        return __("Current Search results for: <span>%1</span>", $test);
    }
}
```

Comment: bro could you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549437/how-to-override-extend-rewrite-class-of-a-third-party-magento-2-x-extension

Comment: i'm trying to overwrite this function but not working : protected function _getProductCollection()

Comment: What file is the first one?! `di.xml`?!

Answer (score 1):

Please add constructor in your block class as below

```
namespace Test\Test\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LayerResolver $layerResolver,
        Data $catalogSearchData,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $catalogSearchData, $queryFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __("Search results for: '%1'", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }
}
```

============== EDIT ==================

Add catalogsearch_result_index.xml in your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="search.result">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_CatalogSearch::result.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I doubt that's the solution as the parent constructor will automatically be called if that code is missing

Comment: Nope not working.

Comment: Updated my answer, please try it

Comment: same result i have no problem in overriding i have problem with phtml are not loading.

Comment: try to set template and see

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112686/magento-2-overriding-block-class-not-generating-output

Answer (score 1):

Update your **Result.php** file as follows

```
namespace Test\Test\Block;

class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LayerResolver $layerResolver,
        Data $catalogSearchData,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $catalogSearchData, $queryFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __("Search results for: '%1'", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to extend **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions**

I had to put the `di.xml` into **etc/frontend/di.xml** instead of **etc/di.xml**

I also had to execute these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo -u projectuser bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

---

**app/code/**`VENDOR`/`MODULE`**/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions"
                type="<<VENDOR>>\<<MODULE>>\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions" />
</config>
```

**app/code/**`VENDOR`/`MODULE`**/Block/Product/View/GalleryOptions.php**

```
<?php

namespace <<VENDOR>>\<<MODULE>>\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery;

class GalleryOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        Json $jsonSerializer,
        Gallery $gallery,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->gallery = $gallery;
        $this->jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonSerializer, $gallery, $data);
    }

    public function getOptionsJson()
    {
        exit("getOptionsJson override called");
       ...
    }

    public function getFSOptionsJson()
    {
        exit("getOptionsJson override called");
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I executed:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo -u projectuser bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Hint:** As you can see there are exits in my function call. If the execution breaks with this exit, then the override was successfull.