# Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select

Tags: magento2, override-block, magento-catalog

**SOLVED :: 15.9.17 (the following code works on a fresh Magento 2.1.7 installation; tested on Luma theme)**

I am struggling with the override of this particular core block

Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select

Here is my module structure:

```
├── <VendorName>
|   ├── <ModuleName>
|   |   ├── Block/
|   |   |   ├── Product/
|   |   |   |   ├── View/
|   |   |   |   |   ├── Options/
|   |   |   |   |   |   ├── Type/
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   └── Select.php
|   |   ├── etc/ 
|   |   |   └── di.xml
|   |   |   └── module.xml
|   |   ├── view/
|   |   |   ├── frontend/
|   |   |   |   ├── templates/
|   |   |   |   |   ├── product/
|   |   |   |   |   |   ├── view/
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   ├── options/
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   ├── type/
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   └── select.phtml
|   |   └── registration.php
```

The registration.php

```
    <?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

The module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
</config>
```

The di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

The select.phtml (copied as it is from vendor/magento folder)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select */ ?>
<?php
$_option = $block->getOption();
$class = ($_option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required' : '';
?>
<div class="field<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class; ?>">
    <label class="label" for="select_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>">
        <span><?php echo  $block->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php echo $block->getValuesHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()): ?>
            <?php if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO || $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX): ?>
                <span id="options-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Select.php (I removed the custom logic here, as I think not relevant in this context)

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions 

{

   public function getValuesHtml()
    {
    // My Custom Code
    }
}
```

According to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112847/51071 I was expecting to succesfully override the block after having activated the module and run setup:di:compile, but nothing happened.

Does anyone has a clue what am I missing here in order to make the module working properly? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers helped me but it did not work for me as it is. 
This is what I did to override block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

**File - [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
    <plugin name="[Vendor]_[Module]_select" sortOrder="10"
            type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"/>
</type>
```

**File - [Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions
{

 public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)
 {
    $_option = $subject->getOption();
    $configValue = $subject->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
    $store = $subject->getProduct()->getStore();

    $subject->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
    // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
    ) {
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';

        $extraParams = '';
        $select = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
            ]
        );
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            // Code changes start
            if($_option->getIsSize()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Size'));
            }
            else if($_option->getIsCut()){
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select a Cut'));
            }
            else{
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Select an Option'));
            }
            // Code changes end
        } else {
            $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . '][]');
            $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
        }
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ],
                false
            );
            $select->addOption(
                $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                ['price' => $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
            );
        }
        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
            $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
        }
        if (!$subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
        }
        $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
        $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

        if ($configValue) {
            $select->setValue($configValue);
        }

        return $select->getHtml();
    }

    if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
        $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
    ) {
        $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
        $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
        $arraySign = '';
        switch ($_option->getType()) {
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                $type = 'radio';
                $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                    $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                        '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '" class="' .
                        $class .
                        ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        ']"' .
                        ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                        ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                        ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                        $_option->getId() .
                        '"><span>' .
                        __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                }
                break;
            case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                $type = 'checkbox';
                $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                $arraySign = '[]';
                break;
        }
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
            $count++;

            $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                [
                    'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                    'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                ]
            );

            $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
            if ($arraySign) {
                $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
            } else {
                $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
            }

            $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
            if ($arraySign) {
                $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
            }

            $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                $require .
                '">' .
                '<input type="' .
                $type .
                '" class="' .
                $class .
                ' ' .
                $require .
                ' product-custom-option"' .
                ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                ' name="options[' .
                $_option->getId() .
                ']' .
                $arraySign .
                '" id="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '" value="' .
                $htmlValue .
                '" ' .
                $checked .
                ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                ' price="' .
                $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                '" />' .
                '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                $_option->getId() .
                '_' .
                $count .
                '"><span>' .
                $_value->getTitle() .
                '</span> ' .
                $priceStr .
                '</label>';
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';
        }
        $selectHtml .= '</div>';

        return $selectHtml;
    }
 }
}
```

Important things to note here - 
After copying \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php to [Vendor][Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php, you must do following.

1. Change the namespace to `[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;`
2. Replace `public function getValuesHtml()` to `public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject, $result)`
3. Replace `$this` to `$subject`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems on your code:

1. You placed `registration.php`  in the wrong place. You should place it under `<VendorName>/<ModuleName>`
2. In `di.xml`, you wrote the code which should be placed in `module.xml`. Instead, you should replace `di.xml` into the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
   </config>
   ```

After that, your code should work.

**===Update 13 Sep 2017===**

Add one point:

3. There are no parent::__construct on this class. You can simply delete whole `__construct` function.

Comment: Thanks for checking.

'registration.php' was actually in the right place already. I have misspelled the schema in the question though (will be editing it)

I have corrected as you suggested the code into 'di.xml' and 'module.xml', but unfortunately still the block has not overriden.

Comment: See my edited di.xml

Comment: Vendor_Module path is correct in my di.xml

Comment: See my update answer

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I confirm that the constructor is not essential here.  Unfortunately thought, I can't get the module to work. I have updated the question with the correct code, but still no result. The module runs on a fresh Magenbto 2.1.7 installation. I don't understand why this block is not overriden.

Comment: Did you enable the module?

Comment: Of course I did. The module is enabled on a fresh Magento 2.1.7 installation, with default Luma theme. There must be something peculiar than I can't find out with this particular Core Block: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select. 
Same module structure and method work perfectly when it comes about overriding other Core Blocks.

Comment: Solved. I found out an inconsistency as for the Class. Declared Class needs to extend \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions, which is parent of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select. I have edited the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your script is being run in Magento i have done something similar with this block so can confirm it works

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```